# Async method return type?

Tags: c#

This is the script I'm trying to ahieve (using CodeDomProvider to compile and run).

```
AddText("Testing. Press yes to continue.");
var answer = SendYesNo();

if (answer)
{
    AddText("Good.");
    SendOk();
} 
else
{
    AddText("Not good.");
    SendOk();
}
```

Now. I want SendYesNo to use a AutoResetEvent, so it halts the script execution until a response has been given. Once a response is set, the auto reset event is also set, so it continues execution and returns the response. For example, what I have so far:

```
public bool SendYesNo()
    {
        this.waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        this.waitHandle.WaitOne();

        return this.Selection;
    }
```

And to set the selection, I use:

```
public void SetSelection(bool selection)
    {
        this.Selection = selection;
        this.waitHandle.Set();
    }
```

However, it doesn't work (nothing happens once I set the response), and the whole program is stuck. Nothing functions. Why's that? I think I have to use async for that, but I'm not sure how. Also, should I use a custom EventHandler for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Show code for `SendYesNo()`. If it's return type is void then how you assigning it to variable ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - you say you want async, but you want the program to wait for a response?  That sounds like you want a blocking operation - i.e., synchronous.

Comment: If you're talking about `await/async`, async methods normally return `Task<T>` (or void in some special cases).  If you don't `await` an async method, you can get the result by calling the `Response` property of the `Task<T>`.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar I'ts a return type of void for now because I don't know how to implement such thing. I just want to know how to "halt" the script (using async/await), and then apply the response to the variable which called the script.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of what `async/await` is (or at least it's not clear based on your question).  [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Comment: @Tim I don't think you understood my question - then. I call the "Run" method from my script which executes that wall of text in the original post. When it executes YesNo (an async method), it halts the scripts until a response is given. I want to know two things: 1) How to halt the script. 2) How to apply the response back to the variable that called it.

Comment: Let me ask this from a different point of view: what should the script be doing while it waits for `SendYesNo()`? The code directly after it requires `SendYesNo()` to have returned already. Using `async/await` with `SendYesNo()` would return control to the caller of the currently executing code until `SendYesNo()` returns a value. *The script would continue to run.* But this sounds like the opposite of what you want to happen.

Comment: @DavidAntaramian I want the script to halt once SendYesNo is called. However, SendYesNo will return a boolean (based on what I set it to) after I set the variable and will resume the script. The variable will be set, for example, with a method called "SetResponse". Once the response is set, SendYesNo will return the response (that I set using SetResponse) and will resume the script.

Comment: @user3265040 - Is there other processing going on outside of the script while you wait for `SendYesNo` to return?  I think the confusion we're having with your question is that `async/await` is designed to allow a program to continue operating while it waits for a return from another method/process, and it sounds like you want the opposite.  Can you post more of the code to give more context?  What you want to accomplish may be obvious to you, as you're writing the code, but it doesn't seem obvious to us.

Comment: If the script is halted how do you call `SetResponse()`? Where do you intend to call `SetResponse()`?

Comment: @Tim I just want to wait until a response has been set and then return the response. I think I can do with event handlers and auto reset event, but I don't know how. Can I use AutoResetEvent.Set, and then use a custom EventHandler (that contains custom EventArgs) to return the arguments?

Comment: I've edited the main post. Sorry.

Comment: It seems you are trying to do a triathlon before you can walk. It sounds like you aren't familiar with all of `CodeDomProvider`, `threading` & `asynchronous programming`, yet you are trying to combine them all together. Try to master each separately before you start mixing them, as it is obvious you can't figure out where your sticking point is between these domains.

Comment: First of all, looking at your edits, how are you defining your threads? What is the result of setting a breakpoint at `this.Selection = selection;`? Does the debugger reach that point?

Answer (score 0):

May be if i understand then you need some thing like this.

```
private Task<bool> SendYesNo()
{
    if (Yes)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and then

```
AddText("Testing. Press yes to continue.");
var answer = await SendYesNo();

if (answer)
{
    AddText("Good.");
    SendOk();
} 
else
{
    AddText("Not good.");
    SendOk();
}
```

Comment: Exactly. However, I also need to know how to WAIT when calling the SendYesNo method until the user sets the response (and how to set the response). For example, once SendYesNo is called, it halts everything. When the user sets the response (using a button, or a code, whatever) - the method returns that response and the script will continue. (Also, How do I convert bool to Task<bool>?).

Comment: @user3265040 - The "conversion" (it's not really a conversion) is handled for you when you use the `await` operator.  `var answer = await SendYesNo();` will return a variable of type `bool`.  It's equivalent to `var answer = SendYesNo().Result;`.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually much simpler than I thought. The framework provides a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` type which does what you want it to.

```
class NpcScript {

    TaskCompletionSource<bool> response = new TaskCompletionSource<bool> ();

    public void SetResponse(bool value) {
        response.SetResult (value);
    }

    async Task<bool> SendYesNo() {
        return await response.Task;
    }


    public async Task Perform() {
        AddText("Testing. Press yes to continue.");
        var answer = await SendYesNo();

        if (answer)
        {
            AddText("Good.");
            SendOk();
        } 
        else
        {
            AddText("Not good.");
            SendOk();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

You should also call Perform from some asynchronous context with await too. For example, lets assume I create a task to handle Perform, and another task which waits for some user input, I can start both tasks, but wait for them all to be completed before continuing execution in the thread.

```
var script = new NpcScript();

var taskPerform = new Task(async () => {
    await script.Perform();
});
taskPerform.Start();

var taskInput = new Task(() =>
    //get user input here
    script.SetResponse (inp);
});
taskInput.Start();

Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { taskPerform, taskInput });
```

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind. However, the whole program seems to stop when I set the response (like, nothing happens).

Comment: Check my edit. You should call Perform asynchronously, but you ultimately need some synchronization point (such as calling Task.Run, Task.Wait)

Comment: Any idea why it calls SendYesNo twice after the response has been given?

Comment: As I've tested it, it only calls SendOK once. Are you sure some other part of your code is not making the other call?